# Is there any difference in meaning between "don't do something," "don't be doing something" and "don't go doing something"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *don't do something*, *don't be doing something* and *don't go doing something*? For example:

> **Don't make** a noise when Dad is working on something!
>
> **Don't be making** a noise when Dad is working on something!
>
> **Don't go making** a noise when your Dad is working on something!

Comment: I don't think so. _Be making_ has more of the idea of ongoing noise, and _go making_ is presumably related to the idiom _to go and do_ something, implying disapproval. BTW, we say _make a noise_.

Comment: @KateBunting , it sounds like you are saying "don't make noise" is incorrect.  Do a search for that expression, in quotes.

Comment: @Sam It appears that some people claim that _Don't make noise_ is idiomatic. This surprises me, as in my British English it would always be _make a noise_.